# bash: iterative extraction of the number from the column

Tags: bash, awk

I am looping million log files, arranged in fixed format: one line with 5 columns:

```
 0    0.258517     0.20418      0.1592    0.258123
```

I need to take the number from the 2nd column and save it to the separate log together with the name of the log file, keeping the following format (so the final log should contain N lines for each of the LOG)

```
name_of_file1: 0.258517
...
name_of_fileN: nnnnnnn
```

Here the possible sollution only lacking some function (AWK??) taking the 2nd column value:

```
   cd foler_with_all_logs
    # do something to extract the number and then add the line with $log_name to >> final_summary.log
    awk '-F, *' '{ printf("%s| %s\n", FILENAME,$2) }' *.log >> final_summary.log
```

Here the problem in my AWK function which does not recognize the format of the second column of my log file.

Comment: Why use `-F, *`? When you can just print `$2` ? Do you have a CSV file?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `cd folder_with_all_logs; awk '{print $2,FILENAME}' * > final_summary.log`?

Comment: Is the second column repeating inside each log file or you have many different values inside each log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you show doesn't look like it is comma separated, so you don't need (or want) `-F,`. It looks like all you want is this:

```
cd folder_with_all_logs 
awk '{print $2,FILENAME}' * > final_summary.log
```

Comment: hey, thank you so much ! In my case the following AWK expression did the job awk '-F ' '{ printf("%s| %s\n", FILENAME,$2) }' ./*.log > final_log.txt

Comment: @user3470313 the `-F` there is useless, the default field delimiter is a space anyway so it isn't doing anything. However, you are now printing `$2|FILENAME` which is not what your question asked for. I'm glad you found what you need, but next time please make sure your question is actually asking for the format you want.

Comment: Actually, using this command it prints FILENAME and than the value from $2, as I indicated in my first topic - I've just double checked it ...

Comment: A *million* log files (4th word in question)? That `*`  has got to go! Also, making a new .log output file in a directory containing log files will possibly read the output file as input too. Wiser to put the output in `..`.